# What does backoffMultiplier mean in DefaultRetryPolicy?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have created new Job retry policy :
    `new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 2, 2);`

So, What does `backoffMultiplier` mean in `DefaultRetryPolicy`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RetryPolicy deals with these three parameters

Timeout - Specifies Socket Timeout in millis per every retry attempt.

Number Of Retries - Number of times retry is attempted.

BackOff Multiplier - A multiplier which is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.

For above example

Timeout - 5000 secs, Num of Attempt - 2, Back Off Multiplier - 2

**Attempt 1**:

time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier );

time = 5000 + 10000 = 15000

Socket Timeout = time;

Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 15 Secs

**Attempt 2**:

time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier );

time = 15000 + 30000 = 45000

Socket Timeout = time;

Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 45 Secs

So at the end of Attempt 2 if still Socket Timeout happenes Volley would throw a TimeoutError in your UI Error response handler.

Comment: "Timeout - 5000 secs" Here 5000 is milliseconds, right?

Comment: Yes, Timeout is 5 seconds

Comment: Answer is copy/paste from here http://beginners-java.blogspot.fi/2015/03/customize-volley-default-retry-policy.html

Answer (score 21):

The marked answer is copied off answer from [this blog](http://beginners-java.blogspot.fi/2015/03/customize-volley-default-retry-policy.html), without credits :(

Here is an explanation of how code calculates it... You can look at the [DefaultRetryPolicy.java](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java) it is open source after all...

When it is initialized, it uses user given values:

```
    /**
     * Constructs a new retry policy.
     *
     * @param initialTimeoutMs The initial timeout for the policy.
     * @param maxNumRetries The maximum number of retries.
     * @param backoffMultiplier Backoff multiplier for the policy.
     */
    public DefaultRetryPolicy(int initialTimeoutMs, int maxNumRetries, float backoffMultiplier) {
        mCurrentTimeoutMs = initialTimeoutMs;
        mMaxNumRetries = maxNumRetries;
        mBackoffMultiplier = backoffMultiplier;
}
```

Therefore when code checks current timeout, it receive the `initialTimeoutMs` value for the first request (not the retry request, original request).

```
    /** Returns the current timeout. */
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return mCurrentTimeoutMs;
    }
```

If a `retry()` is called then it re-calculates the timeout (for the retrt request 2nd, 3rd etc.):

```
/**
 * Prepares for the next retry by applying a backoff to the timeout.
 *
 * @param error The error code of the last attempt.
 */
@Override
public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {
    mCurrentRetryCount++;
    mCurrentTimeoutMs += (int) (mCurrentTimeoutMs * mBackoffMultiplier);
    if (!hasAttemptRemaining()) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

So the back off multiplier is only added if 1st request fails, in the 2nd request (retry request) and so on...

With initialTimeoutMs = 5000ms, maxNumRetries = 2, backoffMultiplier = 2

Timeout for 1st request 5s
Timeout for 2nd request(retry) 5+10 = 15s
Timeout for 3rd request(retry) 15+30 = 45s

So there would be 1 normal request + 2 retries. Totaling 3 requests, because of the code

```
/** Returns true if this policy has attempts remaining, false otherwise. */
protected boolean hasAttemptRemaining() {
    return mCurrentRetryCount <= mMaxNumRetries;
}
```

After 1st request `mCurrentRetryCount` is 0, after 2nd request 1, and after 3rd request 2. Only on 4th request it would return `false` Because `mCurrentRetryCount` is increased only from the `retry()` method.